# AngularJS filter search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have tried the filter logic from angular to one of the unordered list.
But, the search filter is working after typed 3 characters of the name, sometimes giving wrong search results.

```
 <input type='text' ng-model='searchString' placeholder="Search a name..." />


<ul class="nav">
     <li class="active" ng-repeat="item in artists.People | filter :searchString">
           <a href ng-click='setSelectedArtist(item)'>{{item.name}}</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

JSON:

{

```
    "People":[
       {
          "name":"Andrew Amernante",
          "rating":3,
          "img":"http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200",
          "Description":"Gluten­free cray cardigan vegan. Lumbersexual pork belly blog, fanny pack put a bird on it selvage",
          "Likes":[
             "Dogs",
             "Long walks on the beach",
             "Chopin",
             "Tacos"
          ],
          "Dislikes":[
             "Birds",
             "Red things",
             "Danish food",
             "Dead Batteries"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Frank Wang",
          "rating":5,
          "img":"http://www.fillmurray.com/200/201",
          "Description":"Before errors, mails were only pressures. This is not to discredit the idea that a magic is the prose of anelizabeth. This could be, or perhaps some posit the outmost coil to be less than dedal. Some assert that those treatments are nothing more than carp.",
          "Likes":[
             "Frank",
             "Manchester United",
             "Football",
             "Programming"
          ],
          "Dislikes":[
             "Dogs",
             "Long walks on the beach",
             "Chopin",
             "Tacos"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Sissi Chen",
          "rating":5,
          "img":"http://www.fillmurray.com/200/202",
          "Description":"Aaah! Natural light! Get it off me! Get it off me! Oh, loneliness and cheeseburgers are a dangerous mix. D'oh. Here's to alcohol, the cause of all life's problems.",
          "Likes":[
             "Cats",
             "the beach",
             "Chopin",
             "Blue things"
          ],
          "Dislikes":[
             "Birds"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Diego Garcia",
          "rating":2,
          "img":"http://www.fillmurray.com/200/204",
          "Description":"Facts are meaningless. You could use facts to prove anything that's even remotely true! I prefer a vehicle that doesn't hurt Mother Earth. It's a go­cart, powered by my ownsense of self­satisfaction. You don't win friends with salad.",
          "Likes":[
             "Talking Spanish",
             "Spanish food",
             "Spanish things",
             "Football"
          ],
          "Dislikes":[
             "Not talking spanish",
             "Chopin"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Fuad Rashid",
          "rating":4,
          "img":"http://www.fillmurray.com/200/206",
          "Description":"Gluten­free cray cardigan vegan. Lumbersexual pork belly blog, fanny pack put a bird on it selvage",
          "Likes":[
             "Dogs",
             "Long walks on the beach",
             "Chopin",
             "Tacos"
          ],
          "Dislikes":[
             "Birds",
             "Red things",
             "Danish food",
             "Dead Batteries"
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zAfgKxIGsyshedACMF9p?p=info) code.

Ex: Start typing 'si', you will end up with two results where first one(frank wang) is not correct.

And, this is the reference [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/Jkp0zdxNFTKQEEMLYAth/preview) where I'm referring for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to specify which object property, in this case `name` for the `filter` to filter against:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='searchString' placeholder="Search a name..." />

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active" ng-repeat="item in artists.People | filter: { name: searchString }">
    <a href ng-click='setSelectedArtist(item)'>{{item.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You would need to set the initial value of `searchString` to an empty string as well to match against all people when no text has been entered.

```
$scope.searchString = '';
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqKZn1dsrbyHfMravOyQ?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The array has not been loaded from the above code snippet

Comment: You didn't specify an initial value for `searchString`. If you set `$scope.searchString = '';` that should load it. Let me update the answer and Plunker. This does solve the issue of incorrect names displaying when entering characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own customized filter to specify on which property you need to search:

```
$scope.searchTextByName = function(artist){
    if($scope.searchText !== undefined){
        if(artist.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ){
           return artist;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it will match on all JSON value of single people object with your searchText key.